# error while running quartz scheduler in eclipse

Tags: java

```
    package qt;
    import java.util.Date;
    import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.*;
    import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.*;
    import org.quartz.JobDetail;
    import org.quartz.Scheduler;
    import org.quartz.SimpleTrigger;
    import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;


    public class SimpleTriggerExample {
         public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
            {
                JobDetail job = new JobDetail(); //**error: cannot instantiate the type of job detail
                job.setName("dummyJobName"); //**error: mehod setname is undefined for jobDetail
                job.setJobClass(HelloJob.class);

                //configure the scheduler time
   SimpleTrigger trigger = new SimpleTrigger(); /error: cannot instantiate the type of simple trigger
                trigger.setStartTime(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000));
                trigger.setRepeatCount(SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY);
                trigger.setRepeatInterval(30000);

                //schedule it
                Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
                scheduler.start();
                scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

            }


}
```

I have included the necessary jar files...but still I'm getting this error,,can anyone please tell me what is wrong with this program.. and while adding jar I didn find "quartz-all-xxxx" I tried searching in many sites..please tell me.... I'm totally stuck with this.

Comment: JobDetail is an interface(http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/JobDetail.html). Look at JobDetailImpl(http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/impl/JobDetailImpl.html).

Comment: thank you...I'm able to resolve that now.. but now I'm getting an error like "simpleSchedule()" method is undefinrd for the type quartz... should I import any files for this?

Answer (score 0):

`JobDetail` is an interface, you can't instantiate it.

Same with `SimpleTrigger`.

You should probably read up about [Interfaces in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html).

Comment: thank you...I'm able to resolve that now.. but now I'm getting an error like "simpleSchedule()" method is undefinrd for the type quartz... should I import any files for this?

Comment: If you're using a [SimpleScheduleBuilder](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/SimpleScheduleBuilder.html), then yes.